# javac access denied on cmd

Tags: java, command-line, cmd, javac

I'm just trying to run a very simple command on the CMD

```
"javac.exe -help"
```

note that I'm using windows 8 and running the cmd as admin , I get a message said **access denied** 
, here are the system variables :

- JAVA_HOME: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67"
- PATH: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin"
- JAVA_PATH: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_67"

any suggestions ?

Comment: Has it ever worked in the past? Can you open `jdk\bin` folder(s) through console? Are other .exe there (like `java`) accessible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From which directory are you calling?
Btw, javac -help should also work

Comment: That's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Not enough reputation. :( Won't do it again ;)

Comment: Answers like that are nonetheless discouraged. And a good way to loose reputation if someone really dislikes it and thumbs down.

Comment: you are right , using the ".exe" will enforce me to use the jdk path as a directory for the CMD